# Insert into table X amounts of rows given by select statement sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, rows

I'm having a little rough time thinking how can I insert data to a table from different select statements.

I have one table "segments" that has the information of a trip segment (one segment per row). There can be one to 100 segments for one person in one bus trip (reservation).

I need to generate a script that inserts the segments of 10 different reservations to a table. Again.. maybe the reservation number one has 5 rows (segments) and the reservation number 2 has 10 rows. (so 15 rows would be inserted into the table for this 2 reservations)

```
    CREATE TABLE ERR (
  A              VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  B              VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  C              VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  D              TIMESTAMP(6),
  E              VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
  F              VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  G              VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
  H              VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  I              VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  J              VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  K              VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  L              VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  M              VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  N              VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  O              VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  P              NUMBER,
  Q              NUMBER
)    
VARIABLE RL1 VARCHAR2(6 BYTE);
VARIABLE RL2 VARCHAR2(6 BYTE);

BEGIN
SELECT 'AAA123', 'BBB789'
INTO :RL1, :RL2
FROM DUAL;
END;

SELECT :RL1, :RL2 FROM DUAL;


INSERT INTO
  ERR (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q)
SELECT A, B, C, TO_DATE (TRUNC (D), 'DD/MM/YY'), E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q
FROM SEGMENTS_1
WHERE A IN (:RL1)
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C, TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP(D,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')), E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q 
FROM SEGMENTS_2
WHERE A IN (SELECT NEWLOC FROM XREF WHERE OLDLOC = :RL1);
COMMIT;
```

Any ideas?

Also.. declaring 2 variables isn't going well, I need to insert 10 diferent variables..

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Don't use different select statements use a join instead. If you wants more detailed response you'll need to provide more details yourself. Actual table structures, example data, etc. Otherwise it's hard for us to visualise what might be giving you a problem.

Comment: Sorry for that, I will provide more information. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Minimize the problem. I.e. less columns, less data, less tables, smaller query - but still showing the problem.